# Find the Coordinates(X,Y) of Contour detected using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I want to find the coordinate points of the edge detected (green boundaries) using OpenCV-Python. Is there any way to loop through the points and get as many points?

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).